# Как правильно реализовать свой reminder в android?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-handler

Пишу приложение, в котором создаю запись тренировки (она может быть не одна), и в настройках указываю в checkbox включать напоминалку или нет. Необходима, чтобы напоминалка работала в отдельном потоке, и корректно выключалась при изменении значения cheсkBox. Как правильно реализовать такую логику? Может тут нужно использовать handler? Ниже привел пример своего кода.

Я создаю intent, передаю в качестве второго агрумента свой созданный Service (в манифесте для него прописал отдельный процесс).В объекте training, я сохранил необходимое мне время запуска будильника, а также данные checkbox.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class);
intent.putExtra("training", training);
startService(intent);
```

Вот собственно код самого сервиса:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Training training = (Training) intent.getParcelableExtra("training");
        MyAlarm.scheduleNotification(training, getApplicationContext());
        stopSelfResult(startId);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Здесь соответственно реализация MyAlarm:

```
public class MyAlarm {
    public static void scheduleNotification(Training training, Context context) {
        if (training.getRemind() == 1) {

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, training.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();


            Calendar trainingTime = DateTimeParser.getDateTime(training.getTime());
            currentTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, trainingTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, trainingTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            currentTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (Calendar.getInstance().after(currentTime)) {
                currentTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }


            builder.
                    setContentIntent(pIntent).
                    setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                    setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)).
                    setTicker("Нажми на меня").
                    setWhen(currentTime.getTimeInMillis()).
                    setAutoCancel(true).
                    setContentTitle(training.getName()).
                    setContentText("Жми тут!");


            Notification notif = builder.build();


            //Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("START_ALARM");
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, training.getId());
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notif);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("training", training);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, training.getId(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (training.getRemind() == 0) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("START_ALARM");
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, training.getId());
            notificationIntent.putExtra("training", training);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, training.getId(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

И BroadcastReceivera, здесь перезапускую метод scheduleNotification, т.к. setRepeating работает не корретно начиная с API 19:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Log.d("MyLogs", "Receiver Thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

        //Log.e("MyLogs","End");

        Training training = intent.getParcelableExtra("training");
        MyAlarm.scheduleNotification(training, context);

    }


}
```

Comment: да, хандлер вполне подойдет